# Reverse Swipe Through Array of UIButtons

Tags: ios, uibutton, nsmutablearray, uiswipegesturerecognizer

In my app, I have a lot of UIButtons stack on top of each other.  I want to use Swipe Gestures to go back and forth through them.  in viewDidLoad I have:

```
self.buttonArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:map, boardmembers, facebook, twitter, lessonbooks, schedule, nil];
    map.hidden = NO;
    boardmembers.hidden = facebook.hidden = twitter.hidden = lessonbooks.hidden = schedule.hidden = YES;
```

To swipe from right to left, and advance them I have:

```
 UIButton *currentVisibleButton = [_buttonArray firstObject];
    UIButton *nextVisibleButton = [_buttonArray objectAtIndex:1];

    [_buttonArray removeObject:currentVisibleButton];
    [_buttonArray addObject:currentVisibleButton];

    currentVisibleButton.hidden = YES;
    nextVisibleButton.hidden = NO;
```

I am having issues getting the reverse to work, where I can go back AND forth.  How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your code exactly, but the analogous reverse order of what you posted would be:

```
UIButton *currentVisibleButton = [_buttonArray lastObject];
UIButton *nextVisibleButton = _buttonArray[_buttonArray.count-2];

[_buttonArray removeObject:currentVisibleButton];
[_buttonArray insertObject:currentVisibleButton atIndex:0];
```

But a better way to use an array as a ring is to keep a cursor.  Keep state of the currently visible index.

```
@property(assign, nonatomic) NSInteger cursor;

- (void)cursorLeft {
    self.cursor = (self.cursor+1 == _buttonArray.length)? 0 :  self.cursor+1;
}

- (void)cursorRight {
    self.cursor = (self.cursor == 0)? _buttonArray.length-1 :  self.cursor-1;
}

- (UIView *)viewAtCursor {
    return (UIView *)_buttonArray[self.cursor];
}
```

Make sure button at index zero in the array is visible and all the others are hidden.  Now without doing any churning on the array, you can swipe around like this.

```
// swipe left
self.viewAtCursor.hidden = YES;
[self cursorLeft];
self.viewAtCursor.hidden = NO;

// swipe right
self.viewAtCursor.hidden = YES;
[self cursorRight];
self.viewAtCursor.hidden = NO;
```

Comment: Property 'length' not found on NSMutableArray

Comment: my bad.  slipped into javascript for a sec there.  fixed

Comment: Lol.  That works, but only as a standalone for going backwards through the buttons to begin with.  When combined with the code I have in the original post, if you start swiping left to right, it goes backwards through the code.  However, if you start going right to left, you have to swipe twice before it does anything.  I want it to where I can go back and forth through everything smoothly.

Comment: Hmm.  It looks like the two directions combined would make the array act like a ring.  I don't see why an extra swipe would be needed.  Can you add an NSLog to the code for each direction to make sure it's running each time?

Comment: It does run each time.  Order of buttons is what I had posted above.  Going only right to left cycles through perfect.  The first visible one is Map.  When cycling left to right the order I get is:  Lessons Twitter Facebook Map (Next swipe stays on map) then finally Schedule, and then like normal.  Then going in opposite direction it has to run a few times, as if to catch up due to not logging currently Selected button?

Comment: Oh.  I see what's going on.  The code is designed to lie about the currently visible item when you change directions.  Let me post a better approach than what you began with.  2mins.

Comment: I think I follow it, but I get the same property hidden not found

Comment: Got it.  Works flawlessly.  Brilliant.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
- (void)swipeToLeft:(BOOL) moveLeft {
    UIButton *currentVisibleButton = [_buttonArray firstObject];
    UIButton *nextVisibleButton;
    if (moveLeft) {
        nextVisibleButton = [_buttonArray objectAtIndex:1];
    } else {
        nextVisibleButton = [_buttonArray lastObject];
    }
    currentVisibleButton.hidden = YES;
    nextVisibleButton.hidden = NO;
    [_buttonArray removeObject:currentVisibleButton];
    [_buttonArray addObject:currentVisibleButton];
}
```